# Find the following double integral question, Why does my answer sound off?

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

> Let $R$ be the region bounded by the graph of $y=x^2$, $x=0$ and $y=4$ in the first quadrant. Please compute the following double integral:
> $$\iint_R xe^{y^2} \ dx\ dy $$
> Please round off your answer to $1$ decimal place.

My work is the following:$$\begin{align}\iint_Rxe^{y^2}dxdy&=\int_0^4\int_0^\sqrt{y}xe^{y^2}dxdy\\&=\int_0^4\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_0^\sqrt{y}e^{y^2}dy\\&=\frac12\int_0^4ye^{y^2}dy\\&=\frac14\int_0^{16}e^tdt\\&=\frac14[e^t]_0^{16}\\&=\frac14[e^{16}-1]\\&=2221527.4\end{align}$$but it doesn't seem correct

Comment: Look at worked examples in Paul's online math notes, for example.  Over time, build up a library of websites like math24.net, art of problems solving, MathPages, etc which show detailed steps in various types of problems.

Comment: You would start by sketching the region. Then you would use the region to determine the limits of integration. You would also use the region and the integrand to decide in which order of variables to integrate: $dxdy$ or $dydx$.

Comment: I've written your calculation in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), which is preferred as it's legible & searchable.

Comment: Presumably, the reason you're suspicious of your answer is because it's a bit large to be quoted to $1$ decimal place; it's many significant figures. I bet there's a mistake in the problem statement. If $e^{y^2}$ was supposed to be $e^{x^2}$, for example, you'll get a much nicer-looking answer.